# Evaluate $\int \frac{x^2 + x + 1}{(x+1)^2(x+2)}dx$ via partial fractions

Tags: integration

$\int \frac{x^2 + x + 1}{(x+1)^2(x+2)}dx$
= $ \int \frac{Ax+B}{(x+1)} + \frac{Cx+B}{(x+1)^2} + \frac{Dx+E}{x+2}$
= $\int (Ax+B)(x+1)(x+2) + (Cx+B)(x+2) + (Dx+E)(x+1)^2$
= $ \int Ax^3 + 3Ax^2 + 2Ax + Bx^2 + 3Bx + 2B + Cx^2 + 2Cx + Bx + 2B + Dx^3 + 2Dx^2 + Dx + Ex^3 + 2Ex^2 + E$
= $ \int (A + D + E)x^3 + (3A + B + C + 2D + 2E)x^2 + (2A + 2C + 4B + D)x + (4B + E)$

Turn into matrix, find reduced row echelon form to solve system of equations:

$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
3 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
This is where things go wrong, apparently this doesn't reduce down properly :( and I have been relying on RREF to solve systems of equations everytime up until now.

I am also confused where the $x^2 + x + 1$ is supposed to go exactly. I know I put it into the system of equations later but until then, I feel like I kinda just ignored it and left it out of all my work up until then (is that okay?).

Other note: I recognize that this is a proper rational fraction so no long division is nesecary and that this has irreducible factors that are repeated so that is why I split them up into the partial fractions up above in that manner. Did I miss any intermittent steps that made the RREF turn out wrong? I am not sure where I went wrong thus far either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a partial fraction decomposition, one only requires a polynomial on the resulting fraction numerators to be one less than those of the corresponding denominators. In this case the resulting fractions should be
$$\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{B}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{C}{x+2}$$
which simplifies the equations significantly.

Comment: I sometimes think of this as "The number of unknowns (i.e. $A$, $B$, $C$ ...) should equal the degree of the denominator".

Comment: Ah, I used the wrong formula..this was for "irreducible quadratic expressions", but the denominator was already fully reduced!

Answer (score 2):

It must be $$\frac{x^2+x+1}{(x+1)^2(x+2)}=\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{B}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{C}{x+2}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{align}\dfrac{x^2 + x + 1}{(x+1)^2(x+2)}=\dfrac{x^2 + 2x + 1-x}{(x+1)^2(x+2)}=&\dfrac{1}{(x+2)}-\dfrac{  (x+2-2)}{(x+1)^2(x+2)}\\=&\dfrac{1}{(x+2)}-\dfrac{  1}{(x+1)^2}+\dfrac{2}{(x+1)^2(x+2)}\end{align}$

You may use partial fraction decomposition for $$\dfrac{2}{(x+1)^2(x+2)}=\dfrac{A}{x+1}+\dfrac{B}{(x+1)^2}+\dfrac{C}{x+2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint

Let $x+1=y\iff x=?$

$$\dfrac{x(x+1)+1}{(x+1)^2(x+2)}=\dfrac{y^2-y+1}{y^2(y+1)}=\dfrac1{y+1}-\dfrac1{(y+1)y}+\dfrac1{y^2(y+1)}$$

For the last two terms, replace $1$ with $y+1-y$ in the numerator

Answer (score 1):

Another way without having to solve equations:

The function

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2 + x+1}{(x+1)^2 (x+2)}$$

has a simple pole at $x = -2$ and a second order pole at $x = -1$. Let's denote the the singular parts of the expansions around $x = -2$  and $x = -1$ by $P_1(x)$ and $P_2(x)$, respectively. The partial fraction expansion can then be written as:

$$f(x) = P_1(x) + P_2(x)$$

This follows from the fact that $g(x) = f(x) - \left[P_1(x) + P_2(x)\right]$ does not have any singularities, as all the singularities in $f(x)$ have been subtracted by subtracting the ones contained in the singular parts of the Laurent expansions around each pole. This means that $g(x)$ is a rational function without any singularities, therefore $g(x)$ is a polynomial (after removing the removable singularities). However, we can also see that $g(x)$ tends to zero at infinity, therefore $g(x)$ must be identical to zero.

We can easily find $P_1(x)$ by substituting $x=-2$ in the factor multiplying $\frac{1}{x+2}$ in $f(x)$. This yields:

$$P_1(x) = \frac{3}{x+2}$$

We can find $P_2(x)$ without doing all the work needed to expand around $x=-1$ by observing that for large $x$ we have:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x} + \mathcal{O}\left(x^{-2}\right)$$

Therefore we must have:

$$P_2(x) = -\frac{2}{(x+1)} +\mathcal{O}(x+1)^{-2}$$

The leading term of the expansion around $x = -1$ of $f(x)$ is easy to find by substituting $x =-1 $ in the term multiplying $\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$, this is given by $\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$, we therefore have:

$$P_2(x) =\frac{1}{(x+1)^2} -\frac{2}{(x+1)}$$

It thus follows that:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{(x+1)^2} -\frac{2}{(x+1)} +  \frac{3}{x+2}$$

Comment: Interesting approach, I don't recognize terms such as Laurent expansion, pole, and singularity. What branch of math is this? I like to solve system of equations because I have taken linear algebra and its easy to plug a matrix into my calculator to solve by reducing to row echelon form